# Soapui and firefox

Tags: web-services, soapui

What is the deference between testing a wsdl with firefox and soapui ? in firefox may wsdl it's working fine but in soapui, the server return to me the 400 bad request.

Comment: If you add the Raw Request and Raw Response that you see in SoapUi it would be easier to give a specific answer to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firefox showing the WSDL is just an indication that your web service was deployed correctly. But you need soap ui to test each of the methods you expose in the web service, to see your implementations are correct or not. You cannot test that with Firefox.

SOAP Ui is testing tool for web services